# Git objects file modification time

Tags: git, synchronization

I use Git primarily for synchronizing my projects across all my development workstations. But from time to time I use also some other synchronization tools like `rsync` or `FreeFileSync`.

If my project working directories are in sync from Git point of view this does not mean that this is case for my other tools which rely on the file size and file modification time. Modification time will not be the same and it will be reported that the file needs synchronization. This is fine for me for source code files because if I made an update from any side to the other, `git status` will output nothing. Furthermore, I still have the chance to capture any data transfer error at the Git level.

The problem is when synchronizing Git object files. Both sides have the same filename and same content but may have different modification time. In this case I dare not to decide what should be the direction of the synchronization. Checksum based synchronization is not feasible in my case.

The question is why `objects/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` files don't have a modification time that reflect the time of "accommodation" of that object in Git?

Now, is there any setting in Git related to this? Otherwise, did anybody try to make a small shell or Python script to update Git object files to their "birthdates"

Comment: *But from time to time I use also some other synchronization tools like rsync or FreeFileSync.* Don't apply them to Git directories. They don't play well with Git (and/or vice versa). In fact, though, two files in `objects` with the same path name always represent the same data (else one of them is corrupt). The data are compressed in a form that is up to Git though.

Comment: I used to ignore syncing .git directories but at the end I found that .git directories are very useful if they were synced (in my case)

Comment: Well, there *is* a program or two that knows how to sync a Git directory across a network connection using minimal network bandwidth and as few updates as possible. That's `git fetch` (or `git push`)...

Comment: Yes, and this is my primary method that I use more frequent. What I need is the possibility to sync the whole Git database from time to time